# C++ coroutines: implementing task<void>

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-coroutine

So, there I'm trying to comprehend that new & complex concept of the coroutines. Took Clang for it, compiling via `clang++ -std=c++17 -fcoroutines-ts -stdlib=libc++` goes fine.

One of the most useful concepts is `task<>` coroutine type, it's mentioned [here](https://abseil.io/blog/20180713-coroutine-types) and even has a couple interesting implementations, [by Gor Nishanov](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xb1Lu7DMmm1NVkNC)  and [in cppcoro library](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/master/include/cppcoro/task.hpp).

Okay, looked fine to try myself in the simpliest case. So, the goal is to implement something that should work like the following:

```cpp
    {
        auto producer = []() -> task<int> {
            co_return 1;
        };

        auto t = producer();

        assert(!t.await_ready());
        assert(t.result() == 1);
        assert(t.await_ready());
    }
```

The template class `task<>` itself was made quite straightforward:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <optional>

namespace stdx = std::experimental;

template <typename T=void>
struct task 
{
    template<typename U>
    struct task_promise;

    using promise_type = task_promise<T>;
    using handle_type = stdx::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

    mutable handle_type m_handle;

    task(handle_type handle)
        : m_handle(handle) 
    {}

    task(task&& other) noexcept 
        : m_handle(other.m_handle)
    { other.m_handle = nullptr; };

    bool await_ready() 
    { return m_handle.done(); }

    bool await_suspend(stdx::coroutine_handle<> handle) 
    {
        if (!m_handle.done()) {
            m_handle.resume();
        }

        return false;
    }

    auto await_resume() 
    { return result(); }

    T result() const 
    {     
        if (!m_handle.done())
            m_handle.resume();  

        if (m_handle.promise().m_exception)
            std::rethrow_exception(m_handle.promise().m_exception);

        return *m_handle.promise().m_value;
    }

    ~task() 
    {
        if (m_handle)
            m_handle.destroy();
    }

    template<typename U>
    struct task_promise 
    {
        std::optional<T>    m_value {};
        std::exception_ptr  m_exception = nullptr;

        auto initial_suspend() 
        { return stdx::suspend_always{}; }

        auto final_suspend() 
        { return stdx::suspend_always{}; }

        auto return_value(T t) 
        {
            m_value = t;
            return stdx::suspend_always{};
        }

        task<T> get_return_object()
        { return {handle_type::from_promise(*this)}; }

        void unhandled_exception() 
        {  m_exception = std::current_exception(); }

        void rethrow_if_unhandled_exception()
        {
            if (m_exception)
                std::rethrow_exception(std::move(m_exception));
        }
    };

};
```

Couldn't really make a smaller piece of code complete and compilable, sorry. Anyway it worked somehow, but there still remained the case of `task<void>`, it's usage could be like the following:

```cpp
    {
        int result = 0;

        auto int_producer = []() -> task<int> {
            co_return 1;
        };

        auto awaiter = [&]() -> task<> { // here problems begin
            auto i1 = co_await int_producer();
            auto i2 = co_await int_producer();

            result = i1 + i2;
        };

        auto t = awaiter();

        assert(!t.await_ready());
        t.await_resume();
        assert(result == 2);
    }
```

The latter didn't seem a problem at all, it looked like `task_promise<U>` required a specialization for `void` (could be a non-template struct without that void case). So, I tried it:

```cpp
    template<>
    struct task_promise<void>
    {
        std::exception_ptr  m_exception;

        void return_void() noexcept  {}

        task<void> get_return_object() noexcept
        { return {handle_type::from_promise(*this)}; }

        void unhandled_exception() 
        { m_exception = std::current_exception(); }

        auto initial_suspend() 
        { return stdx::suspend_always{}; }

        auto final_suspend() 
        { return stdx::suspend_always{}; }
    };
```

Neat and simple... and it causes segfault without any readable stacktrace =(
Works fine when `task<>` is changed to any non-void template, like `task<char>`.

What is wrong with my template specialization? Or am I missing some tricky concept with those coroutines?

Would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Don't know about coroutine, but I know Clang has many bugs related to member specializations. You could define `task_promise` as a non template member and just specialize the member. Make sure to declare the specialization before any instantiation of `task` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zgZ7lX)

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Have you tried compile+run with GCC or MSVC ?

Comment: @Oliv, thanks, but this awkward coroutine mechanics requires the whle promise class to be a template in this case, as far as I get it. I'll try to deal with templates more carefully, the way you showed anyway.

Comment: @darune, MSVC 2019 could show something, I'm just afraid of it being even _more_ buggy, it had troubles even with complex SFINAE in previous versions.
But [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-coroutines) looks like their coroutine support is still in under development, right?

Comment: @Oliv, omg, it worked! Was my fault, you were totally right, because I was trying to make `task_promise` a template and create it's specialization inside the container template. After a good sleep and coffee I tried your solution -- non-template promise and member specialization and it worked in Clang 7 just fine. Had to read your comment thoughtfully. Thanks a lot!
Plz, consider writing an answer, it solved my problem=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the usual suspect was the criminal: specialization! From the standard itself [[temp.expl.spec]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#7)

> When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.

To avoid issue, let's make it as simple as possible: `task_promise` can be a non template and the member specialization is declared as soon as possible:

```
template<class T=void>
struct task{
  //...
  struct task_promise{
    //...
    };
  };

//member specialization declared before instantiation of task<void>;
template<>
struct task<void>::task_promise{
  //...
  };
```